# Counterexample output of Z3

Tags: z3

When a formula in Z3 is unsat and (get-proof) is specified there is an output which I don't find any information about what it is. Where can I find any documentation about that?

Seems to me quite unreadable, is there possibly any tool that takes this as an input?

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: The command `(get-unsat-core)` seems to be what you want. Official example: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/smtc_core

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "proofs" produced by Z3 are not for human consumption.
An outdated version of the format is described in the paper: [Proofs and Refutations, and Z3](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/iwil08.pdf). The [`z3_api.h` file](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/z3_api.h) has a long description of each one of the proof rules. The proof rule identifiers start with `Z3_OP_PR`. I am aware of two applications that use the Z3 proof objects. The following papers contain a lot of examples, and describe how the proof objects can be used.

1. Isabelle Interactive Theorem Prover: Z3 proofs are reconstructed inside of Isabelle using a trusted core. You can find several papers describing this work and the Z3 proof format at [Sascha Bohme's homepage](http://www21.in.tum.de/%7Eboehmes/)
2. [Generation of interpolants](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/ragerdl/fmcad11/papers/81.pdf)

   As pad said, `unsat-cores` are much simpler to use.

Comment: Thank a lot for your links. I will take a look at both methods. So also thanks to @pad !