# How to make z3 generate proof of unsatisfiability?

Tags: z3, sat

I am trying to use z3 from the **command line** as a SAT solver, but I can't figure out how to make it generate a proof of unsatisfiability. No matter what I do, it just prints "unsat" with no explanation, and nothing I can find online has helped. I tried passing `proof=true` on the command line, but nothing changed.

```
../z3-4.8.6-x64-ubuntu-16.04/bin/z3 proof=true unsat_core=true test_tx.cnf 
unsat
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29577754/1959808

Answer (score 1):

z3 can generate proofs in SMTLib mode (though the proof format is rather unspecified.) I'm not sure if it can even generate proofs in the CNF mode at all, though it certainly should be possible. Your best bet might be to file an issue at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues and see if this is supported.